# Java library for converting NFA to DFA

Tags: java, dfa, state-machine, nfa

I am looking for a Java library which can convert Non-deterministic Finite Automaton to Deterministic Finite Automaton.
Is there any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably have a look at JAutomata:

http://jautomata.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You shoukd definitely try the Brics automaton library: http://www.brics.dk/automaton/